# can I configure ngnix anyways other than through the normal ngnix.conf file

Tags: nginx

Is there any way I can configure ngnix other than through the normal ngnix.conf file ?

Like xml configuration or memcache or any other ways..?

My objective is to add/remove upstreams to the configuration dynamically. Ngnix doesnt seem to have a direct solution for this so I was planning to play with the configuration file, but I am finding it very difficult and error prone to modify the file through script/programs.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can't. The only way to "dynamically" reconfigure nginx is to process the config files in external software and then reload the server. Neither you can "program" config like in Apache. The nginx config is mostly a static thing which is praised for its performance.

Source: I needed it too, done some research.

Edit: I have a "supervising" tool installed on my hosts that monitors load and clusters and such. I've ended up implementing the upstreams scaling through it. Whenever a new upstream is ready, it notifies my "supervisor" on all web servers. The "supervisors" then query for served "virtual hosts" on the new upstream and add all of them to their context on the nginx host. then it just `nginx -t && nginx -s reload` everything. This is for nginx fastcgiing to php-fpms.

Edit2: I have many `server` blocks for different server_names (sites), each has an upstream associated to it on another host(s). In the server block I have `include /path/to/where/my/upstream/configs/are/us-<unique_site_id>.conf` line. the `us-<unique_site_id>.conf` is generated when the `server` block is created and populated with existing upstream(s) information. When there are changes in the upstreams pool or the site configuration, the file is rewritten to reflect it.

Comment: :). Thanks for the information. I did find an addon named 'dynamic upstream' but it doesnt help me to add a new upstream. I am kind of desperate to have this functionality of adding upstreams dynamically...  you wanted this functionality ? what did you end up with ? Did you dump nginx or did you tweak something ?

Comment: "and add all of them to their context on the nginx host." how did you do it ?

Comment: Ha ha .. I am completely new to nginx , I didnt know that I can split the configuration into multiple files. Thanks for all the help..